# Recv() call hangs after remote host terminates

Tags: c++, c, sockets

My problem is that I have a thread that is in a recv() call. The remote host suddenly terminates (without a close() socket call) and the recv() call continues to block. This is obviously not good because when I am joining the threads to close the process (locally) this thread will never exit because it is waiting on a recv that will never come.

So my question is what method do people generally consider to be the best way to deal with this issue? There are some additional things of note that should be known before answering:

- There is no way for me to ensure that the remote host closes the socket prior to exit.
- This solution cannot use external libraries (such as boost). It must use standard libraries/features of C++/C (preferably not C++0x specific).

I know this has likely been asked in the past but id like to get someones take as to how to correct this issue properly (without doing something super hacky which I would have done in the past).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to continue to use blocking sockets, you can use the [`SO_RCVTIMEO` socket option](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket):

```
   SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO
          Specify the receiving or sending  timeouts  until  reporting  an
          error.   The parameter is a struct timeval.  If an input or out-
          put function blocks for this period of time, and data  has  been
          sent  or received, the return value of that function will be the
          amount of data transferred; if no data has been transferred  and
          the  timeout has been reached then -1 is returned with errno set
          to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK just as if the socket was specified  to
          be  nonblocking.   If  the  timeout is set to zero (the default)
          then the operation will never timeout.
```

So, before you begin receiving:

```
struct timeval timeout = { timo_sec, timo_usec };
int r = setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
assert(r == 0); /* or something more user friendly */
```

If you are willing to use non-blocking I/O, then you can use `poll()`, `select()`, `epoll()`, `kqueue()`, or whatever the appropriate event dispatching mechanism is for your system. The reason you need to use non-blocking I/O is that you need to allow the system call to `recv()` to return to notify you that there is no data in the socket's input queue. The example to use is a little bit more involved:

```
for (;;) {
    ssize_t bytes = recv(s, buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_DONTWAIT);
    if (bytes > 0) { /* ... */ continue; }
    if (bytes < 0) {
        if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
            struct pollfd p = { s, POLLIN, 0 };
            int r = poll(&p, 1, timo_msec);
            if (r == 1) continue;
            if (r == 0) {
                /*...handle timeout */
                /* either continue or break, depending on policy */
            }
        }
        /* ...handle errors */
        break;
    }
    /* connection is closed */
    break;
}
```

Comment: Couple questions about this: Would there be anyway to tell if the socket was in fact closed using this process? I ask this because in my case I have the possibility that sockets will be open for a large amount of time (think hours) before they are suddenly used. If the timeout is triggered will errno be set to endpoint not connected? Also what is the platform availability of this socket option?

Comment: You test if the socket was closed by calling `recv()` again. You can use `MSG_DONTWAIT|MSG_PEEK` flags to check to see if there is data, no data, or if the socket is closed (in which case `0` is returned). The `errno` is set to `EAGAIN`, so you decide how you want to handle the timeout. The option is advertised on Linux, and is defined in POSIX.

Comment: Excellent, If recv() will block on the second call if the socket is still available (which it looks like it does from your description) this might work out well (assuming Cray supports this sockopt, which it **should** since its in the standard but thats not a guarantee). Thanks.

Comment: This is probably the best solution, but thread cancellation (`pthread_cancel`) would also be a viable solution. To use it correctly, you'd need to setup cancellation cleanup handlers and block cancellation at points where it's not safe to cancel.

Comment: The SO_RCVTIMEO works for blocking socket in most cases, but I got some cases client socket was stuck on recv() when server terminated (RST) connection. Any idea?

Comment: @Jeffery: I would not know for certain without more information. It might be that your network is lossy, and some of the resets have been lost. It might be a software problem. I would recommend asking a question and provide some details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use TCP keep-alive probes to detect if the remote host is still reachable.  When keep-alive is enabled, the OS will send probes if the connection has been idle for too long; if the remote host doesn't respond to the probes, then the connection is closed.

On Linux, you can enable keep-alive probes by setting the `SO_KEEPALIVE` socket option, and you can configure the parameters of the keep-alive with the `TCP_KEEPCNT`, `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, and `TCP_KEEPINTVL` socket options.  See [`tcp(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp) and [`socket(7)`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) for more info on those.

Windows also uses the [`SO_KEEPALIVE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee470551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) socket option for enabling keep-alive probes, but for configuring the keep-alive parameters, use the [`SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS` ioctl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd877220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use select()

From http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
           fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

select() blocks until the first event (read ready, write ready, or exception) on one or more file descriptors or a timeout occurs.

Comment: Select is an option, What happens in the case where the above scenario occurs? I am assuming "exception" would be given in this case correct?

Comment: The server example here is worth reviewing and might be pretty close to what you need:  http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html#Server-Example

Comment: I believe the server example explains that on client disconnect, select() returns read ready on the socket, but the read will read 0 bytes and that signifies a disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

sockopts and `select` are probably the ideal choices.  An additional option that you should consider as a backup is to send your process a signal (for example using the `alarm()` call).  This should force any syscall in progress to exit and set `errno` to `EINTR`.

Comment: I did consider alarm(). However since this is a library I cannot guarantee that the user of the library is not catching the signal.

Comment: Regardless of how/whether the signal is handled, its delivery will cause system calls in progress to exit.

Comment: @BrianCain: That is incorrect. An unhandled `SIGALRM` will terminate the process. A handled one might or might not interrupt blocking functions, depending on whether the signal handler was installed without or with `SA_RESTART`. And an ignored signal would do nothing. As this is library code, it has no business messing with the signal disposition/handler, so this is not a viable approach. Even if it were, you would have no control over which thread the `SIGALRM` would be delivered too, so that's a show-stopping problem too.