# How to use ConnectEx/DisconnectEx pointer on Windows?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I got connectex/disconnectex working I tested they work but how do I reuse socket with them? I saw [Reusing socket descriptor on connection failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237489/reusing-socket-descriptor-on-connection-failure) but they say to loop the whole socket again and I don't want that (they say to go back to creating socket)? I just want to make a new socket once recv fails because host is offline (I'm doing a tcp client).

Thank you.

Comment: I need to set flag to SO_REUSEADDR to reuse socket or just do it the way its linked in the link I posted?

Comment: or I use my recv function like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226876/recv-call-hangs-after-remote-host-terminates ?